# Pydroid3 cannot access python binary

Tags: python, android, pydroid

I removed python 3.9 binary from pydroid3 and replaced it with python 3.10 binary by linking from another directory.After creating symlink to linked binary as root,i gave ownership to the user that pydroid3 use,but pydroid3 didn't have permission to access those symlinks.So i recreated the symlinks as pydroid3 user after which they worked fine but i was still not able to execute the python 3.10 binary

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIzQD.jpg

Comment: Please post the image as text, not the screenshot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.